# div is not moving from left to right correctly

Tags: jquery

Below is my code snippet which i am using to move a div from left to right.

https://jsfiddle.net/nf6pqbr0/1/u/

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  var stop = $(".stopdiv").offset().left;
  var obj = document.getElementById("audio"); 

  $( ".move" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: stop-($(".stopdiv").width()+$(this).width()),
  }, {
    duration: 1000, 
    step: function(){
        $('.sound').each(function(){

            });

  }, complete: function() {
    $(this).css('left',0);
    $(this).css('height','100%');

  }});


});
```

Comment: Is this what you were going for? https://jsfiddle.net/nf6pqbr0/6/

Comment: updated question with tag for div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To set a left to element you should set the position to it
>   `relative/fixed/absolute`

**In your case set the position to relative for .move**

```
.move{position:relative;background:green;width:2px; height:100px;}
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nf6pqbr0/2/)

Another [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nf6pqbr0/5/) you can take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but you can try it:

```
$( "#go_right" ).click(function() {
  $( ".stopdiv" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});

$( "#go_left" ).click(function(){
  $( ".stopdiv" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qne0skd/